# publish subscribe callback handler for python dask

Tags: python, rabbitmq, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to use the publish-subscribe pattern in dask distributed to broadcast a message. Is there a chance to add a callback-handler for the subscribers staying in the dask environment?

Edit:
What about queueing of published topics? E.g. the publisher sends many messages of the same topic ('foo'), which is subscribed by one or many consumers. When a consumer takes a while to handle the first message, what happens to the following messages, that arrive in the meantime? Are they queued or dropped?

Edit2:
I attached a sample snippet showing the occuring behaviour:

```
# main:
    s = Sub('foo')
    client.submit(task)
    n=0
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        print("Waiting for notification, n: {}\n".format(str(n)))
        print(s.get())
# Task:

    mydict= {
        'name' : 'DEADBEEF',
        'handler' : 1234
    }
    p = Pub('foo')
    for n in range(1000):
        mydict['n'] = n
        p.put(mydict)
```

Output is shown below. I don't really get the point here. Are messages dropped or is the message itself just a reference to the counter variable `n`, which isn't locked or copied?

```
{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 984

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 985

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 986

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 987

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 988

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 989

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 990

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 991

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 992

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 993

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 994

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 995

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 996

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 995}
Waiting for notification, n: 997

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 996}
Waiting for notification, n: 998

{'name': 'DEADBEEF', 'handler': 1234, 'n': 999}
Waiting for notification, n: 999
```